# How to use jaydata with Nodejs and krakenJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jaydata, kraken.js

From a tutorial, I get the code below:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Vav84nA_Sg&list=PL1LlnouBcIIDUwyUq9kzngcFDcfhvP0iw&index=26

I am using krakenJS, NodeJS, Jaydata, MongoDb. When I run the server, and navigate to localhost:8000/ , it shows to following error:

```
Internal server error

The URL / had the following error TypeError: Cannot call method 'resolveSetOperations' of undefined.
```

I am not familiar with any of the above technology. Hope someone can give me a hand. How to debug?Where to look up Jaydata's documentation on Mongodb provider? Thanks.

controllers/index.js

```
'use strict';


var IndexModel = require('../models/index');


module.exports = function (router) {

var model = new IndexModel();


router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var $data = require('jaydata');

    $data.Class.define('Product',$data.Entity,null,{
    id:{type:'id',key:true,computed:true,nullable:false},
    title:{type:'string'},
    date:{type:'string'},
    description:{type:'string'},
    price:{type:'int'},
    category:{type:'string'},
    teaserUrl:{type:'string'}
},null);

    $data.Class.defineEx('Database',[$data.EntityContext,$data.ServiceBase],null,{
    Products:{type:$data.EntitySet,elementType:Product}
});

    var db = new Database({name:'mongoDB',
    databaseName:'ScreencastEcommerce',
    address:'localhost',
    port:27017});
    db.Products.toArray(function  (products) {
        res.render('admin/products',{
            title:'Admin - Products',
            prodcuts:products
        });
    });
    // res.render('index', model);

});

};
```

Comment: Entirely as a side note: requiring things inside your handler is rather late in the game. Generally you'll want to do that higher up in the file, so things are resolved early.

Answer (score 0):

The two pieces are orthogonal. The error you're getting isn't specific to kraken at all. It looks like the method `resolveSetOperations` comes from jaydata's `StorageProviderBase`. Perhaps something you're writing needs to inherit from that and does not.